# NSIS Selections Page

Tags: nsis

I was originally going to ask how to do several of the features I how have working in the set file. so I have 2 questions now. Patting myself on the back since I figured out everything else:)

Ok so here is what I would like:

Is it possible to have the list taller so no scrolling?  also
Can we have the title be just that and no checkbox? (They are radio-buttons and the title is the grouping of them)

How could I go about creating the same thing just in a custom page so I have control over the elements?  (including the mouse move over feature of components page)

Thanks for looking and hope you can help me code it out.

Code: (And yes I know the !included's are not all needed in the test buy my app does so I just left it) Also the verification and a few other settings are not finished, I was just getting some examples to work.)

```
!include WinVer.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include x64.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include MUI.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include InstallOptions.nsh
!include Sections.nsh 

!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Please select the options that best match your setup and preferances."
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_TEXT_COMPLIST " "
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Setup Options"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT " " 
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_smallDESC
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH



!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


SectionGroup /e "!Sets" SetsTitle #Section Should be Radio Buttons

  Section "Set 1" Set1
  SectionEnd

  Section /o "Set 2" Set2
  SectionEnd

  Section /o "Skip" SetSkip
  SectionEnd

SectionGroupEnd


SubSection /e "!Setup" SetupTitle #Section Should be Radio Buttons

  Section "Setup 1" setup1
  SectionEnd

  Section /o "Setup 2" setup2
  SectionEnd

  Section  /o "None" setupNone
  SectionEnd

SubSectionEnd


SubSection /e "!AutoLoad" ALTitle #Section Should be Radio Buttons

  Section "Yes" ALYes
  SectionEnd

  Section /o "No" ALNo
  SectionEnd

SubSectionEnd

SubSection /e "!Disable Feature" DFTitle #Section Should be Check Boxes

    Section  "Feature 1" DAF1
    SectionEnd

    Section "Feature 2" DAF2
    SectionEnd

SubSectionEnd

!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SetsTitle} "Sets Description"
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Set1} "Set1 Description"
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Set2} "Set2 Description"
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SetSkip} "SetNone Description"
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END


Section -InstallSelectedOptions

${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${set1}
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "set1"
${endif}

${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${set2}
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "set2"
${endif}


${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${setskip}
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_USERICON|MB_TOPMOST "setnone"
${endif}


${If} ${Setup1} == true

${endif}


SectionEnd

Function .onInit

  StrCpy $1 ${set1} ; Group 1 - Option 1 is selected by default
  StrCpy $2 ${setup1} ; Group 2 - Option 1 is selected by default

FunctionEnd

Function .onSelChange
  !insertmacro StartRadioButtons $1
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${set1}
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${set2}
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${setskip}
  !insertmacro EndRadioButtons

  !insertmacro StartRadioButtons $2
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${setup1}
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${setup2}
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${setupNone}
  !insertmacro EndRadioButtons

FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine radio buttons and checkmarks on the built-in components page but you can use your own custom radio button .BMP file with `!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_CHECKBITMAP "myradio.bmp"`.

You can customize the MUI components page a little bit by defining `MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_SMALLDESC` or `MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_NODESC` but if you need more than that you have to copy and modify "...\NSIS\Contrib\UIs\modern.exe" with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and apply this custom UI with `MUI_UI`.

Replicating the components page as a custom page might be possible but it is a lot of work. nsDialogs does not have much support for the TreeView control so you are pretty much on your own if you go down this route.